# Chop or truncate to n significant digits

Tags: julia

Julia has a built-in function to round to `n` significant digits. `signif(0.0229, 2)` will round to two significant digits and give `0.023`.

How can I chop or truncate to `n` significant digits so that I would get `0.022` instead?

Comment: Will `myfloor(x,d) = round(x-0.5*10.0^(-d),d)` be good enough?

Comment: `myfloor(0.0229, 2)` yields `0.02`, it should yield `0.022`

Comment: Ah... I see, misunderstood the question. But have a lengthy but working suggestion in an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `signif` was removed as of Julia 1.0.

However, now [Base.round](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.round-Tuple%7BType,%20Any%7D) accepts the sigdigits keyword:

```
julia> round(pi, digits=3)
3.142

julia> round(pi, sigdigits=3)
3.14
```

The same works for `trunc`, `ceil`, and `floor`.

Source: [mforets on Github](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/21101#issuecomment-446958508) and @DNF in the comments.

---

Comment: And the same works with `trunc`, `ceil` and `floor`.

Comment: I think it would be useful, actually, if you expand this answer a bit, include `trunc/ceil/floor` and also mention that the `signif` function was removed in v1.0. This would be the updated correct answer for v1.

Comment: This is a better answer for recent versions of Julia. `trunc(0.0229, sigdigits=2)` is a much simpler answer. The original question was over six years ago well before 1.0 existed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, not very imaginative. Used `@edit signif(0.229,2)` to find the source and replace `round` with `floor` (and added a `Base.` for correct Module referencing). Here is the result:

```
function mysignif(x::Real, digits::Integer, base::Integer=10)
    digits < 1 && throw(DomainError(digits, "`digits` cannot be less than 1."))

    x = float(x)
    (x == 0 || !isfinite(x)) && return x
    og, e = Base._signif_og(x, digits, base)
    if e >= 0 # for numeric stability
        r = trunc(x/og)*og
    else
        r = trunc(x*og)/og
    end
    !isfinite(r) ? x : r
end
```

Giving:

```
julia> mysignif(0.0229,2)
0.022
```

Comment: Impressive. It doesn't handle negative numbers correctly. I'm sure that you can easily fix that.

Comment: @clay Yes it is easily fixed (in fact, the desired behavior on negatives depends on the application). To fix, replace `floor` with `trunc` [I'll do it in the answer, as well]

Answer (score 2):

I found a version in Maple and ported to Julia:

```
function signifChop(num, digits)
    if num == 0.0 then
        return num
    else
        e = ceil(log10(abs(num)))
        scale = 10^(digits - e)
        return trunc(num * scale) / scale
    end
end

# Test cases for signifChop
println("$(signifChop(124.031, 5))")
println("$(signifChop(124.036, 5))")
println("$(signifChop(-124.031, 5))")
println("$(signifChop(-124.036, 5))")
println("$(signifChop(0.00653, 2))")
println("$(signifChop(0.00656, 2))")
println("$(signifChop(-0.00653, 2))")
println("$(signifChop(-0.00656, 2))")
```